# Static function receives wrong parameters

Tags: c++, parameters, static, constants, instance

I have this strange behaviour with a static function and can't find a solution. This is from a computer player I am writing for a school project. For the context: Board and Evaluation are classes used by my logic but their functionality is not of importance here.

I have a Class MatchUnit which has a method to create an instance and a constructor assigning local fields:

```
static void MatchUnit::CreateInstance(Board& realBoard, Board& altBoard, unsigned char turn, char currentPlayer)
{
    // [P2]
    _instance = new MatchUnit(realBoard, altBoard, turn, currentPlayer);
    return _instance;
}

MatchUnit::MatchUnit(Board& realBoard, Board& altBoard, unsigned char turn, char currentPlayer)
{
    _realBoard = &realBoard;
    _altBoard = &altBoard;
    _turn = _moveNr = turn;
    _currentPlayer = currentPlayer;
}
```

The fields an methods are defined in in `MatchUnit.h`

```
class MatchUnit {
public:
    static MatchUnit* CreateInstance(Board& realBoard, Board& altBoard, unsigned charturn, char currentPlayer);
private:
    Board* _realBoard;
    Board* _altBoard;
    uchar _turn;
    uchar _moveNr;
    char _currentPlayer;
    MatchUnit(Board& realBoard, Board& altBoard, unsigned char turn, char currentPlayer);
};
```

MatchUnit is a singleton but I left the getter and the field of the instance out, because I don't think they matter here.

Board contains a non static private evaluation pointer (`Evaluation* _eval`)

In my main function I now call the problematic method:

```
Board* realboard = new Board();
Board* altboard = new Board();

// Internally the board constructors assigned their field pointers:
// _eval = new Evaluation();

// [P1]
MatchUnit::CreateInstance(*realboard, *altboard, 0, currentPlayer);
```

If I use the debug view of VS2015 and pause at [P1] I can see that the _eval fields of the boards are not pointing to null. But when I continue to point [P2] they are pointing to null! Other fields of the boards also have strange values, a bool set to true before is false and integers seem to have random values, different from each other!

Why are the parameters of `CreateInstance` totally different from what I gave them?

Comment: Missing return type for `MatchUnit::CreateInstance` definition...

Comment: @Genuigr Okay let me see if I have got your question right once you call the function  
MatchUnit::CreateInstance(*realboard, *altboard, 0, currentPlayer);
And reach [P2] in the code the parameter values at P1 and P2 are different which should be same as you are passing the same thing as parameter.

Comment: @Xtreme_Enigma Yes you got it right.
I corrected the return type. It returns nothing, it just creates an instance and set the static _instance field

Comment: @Genuigr Can you share results at point [p1] and [p2]??? Also if possible the values of the _eval fields after the function has been executed? A possible [p3] if you may?

Comment: You should write a [mcve].

Comment: I got the values you asked for and then at [p3] that point after invoking the function the _eval fields were correctly set. I propably debugged wrong. Strangely I still (later on when running my program) _eval is null again. The bug is somewhere else in the code.This question should be deleted :/

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the function `CreateInstance` differs in your header and source. In your source, you declare the third parameter to be of the type `uchar`, whereas you declare it as `unsigned (int)` in your header (probably due to mistyping a space). When you call your function, the compiler generates code that matches the parameters in your header, while your function uses the parameters as defined in your source. Due to a mismatch in the sizes of the parameters, your function seems to receive the wrong values. You can solve this by simply editing either one of the parameter definitions.

Comment: I corrected that thank you. In my program that is not the problem this was just a fault in me copying my code. Thanks.

Comment: It was an implausible explanation.  Depending on the platform, the argument will be passed in a register (in which the other values are undisturbed), or on the stack (where stack values will tend to be kept at least 32-bit aligned).  Of course, the typo would have been undefined behaviour, but it was unlikely to provoke a run-time error.  It was *very* likely to provoke compile or link-time errors though.